# Has anyone used Enterprise Architect to reverse engineer perl?

Tags: perl, templates, code-generation, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

I would like to reverse engineer a perl application in Enterprise Architect.

I have created perl as a New Language in Settings -> Code Generation Templates and I am guessing that I need a template for a new file, Attribute/Declaration, Operation/Declaration/Body.

I also guess that the operation should indicate "sub xxx" and the operation should indicate "x=y", however I am getting a bit stuck as to how to do this.

I can't be the first person to reverse perl so is there any Code Generation Templates out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, EA does not (in version 10.0.1009) natively support forward or reverse engineering of perl.

Secondly, these templates, which are part of the Code Template Framework, are for code generation only: they cannot be used for reverse engineering.

What you want instead is the Grammar Framework (see the help file under Extending UML Models -- MDG Technology SDK). This allows you to construct a grammar for a language, which specifies what UML elements EA should create when reading source files in that language.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much.  I spent the best part of a week going round in circles and not achieving anything.  There are some examples in C:\Program Files\Sparx Systems\EA\Code Samples, I'm going to work through them then set about creating perl equivalents.